# Convert H264 video stream into RTSP url

Tags: video, h.264, rtsp

I have a stream of h264 video data. I want to stream this h264 video over RTSP.

Is there any recommended library or sample code to do this? I would prefer java, node, or python.

Thanks

Comment: Live555 is a best library but its in c++, Don't know if that helps in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have raw h264 file:

1. Wrap it in a container
   Convert it into one of the supported containers (mp4,flv,webm etc...). You can use **ffmpeg** for the conversion.
2. Stream it with a server
   You can use **ffserver** for streaming it with RTSP
   Check out this link. http://www.alkannoide.com/2013/07/04/play-with-ffserver-a-quick-overview/